# Spring Boot: use database config from WildFly's standalone.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm currently developing an REST app whith Spring boot. For development, I hardcode my database configuration in `application.properties`. However, this app is going to be deployed on different WildFly servers, each of them defining their DB config (user credentials) in `standalone.xml`.

As I'm a newbe to Spring/Java, here is my question: How can I use the DB config from standalone for my spring app?

I already did some research. What I got is to define Services with an `@PersistenceContext` annotated  entity manager. But how can I use it without defining new services, just by using plain JpaRepositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wildfly you will have a datasource configured with at JNDI name.

Instead of configuring url, username and password you have to configure this JNDI name:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/myGreatDS
```

That's all.